# jquery.ajax post data problems

Tags: jquery, shopify

I've created a jsfiddle non working example of my code. This is probably a trivial task for someone with javascript or jquery function experience.

http://jsfiddle.net/xphtxkhf/8/

I'm trying to use the shopify ajax api to add products with line items to my cart just so you know.

My shopify app receives json like this:

```
var json = '{"line_items":[{"variant_id":"123456789","quantity":4,"properties":{"Line 1":"Some Value 1","Line 2":"Some Value 2","Line 3":"Some Value 3"}}],"products":[{"variant_id":"987654321","quantity":1},{"variant_id":"456987123","quantity":4}],"attributes":[{"lookup":"lookup value"}]}';
```

Here is my code to parse it and try to prep "data" for the jquery.ajax post. In the code comments you'll see where I'm stumped due to a lack of javascript fundamentals understanding. I can't figure out how to stuff "data" into the "params" being sent to jquery.ajax.

In the code you'll see an example of how the data would work in a jquery.post, but using jquery.ajax it seems the data needs to be a string? If so, how would I emulate with a string, the jquery.post example? Anyway, I'm so confused at this point I'm not even sure how to ask the question properly. I've been looking at json.stringify, but I'm not sure at this point. Probably a really simple answer.

```js
var queue = [];
var attributesQueue = [];
var data = [];
var properties = [];
var moveAlong;

console.log(json);

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( json );

$.each(obj.line_items, function(index, element) {
    queue.push( { 
        type: 'line_item',
        variantId: element.variantId,
        quantity: parseInt(element.quantity) || 0,
        properties: // need to put properties here
    });
});
    
$.each(obj.products, function(index, element) {
    queue.push( { 
        type: 'product',
        variantId: element.variantId,
        quantity: parseInt(element.quantity) || 0
    });
});
    
$.each(obj.attributes, function(index, element) {
    attributesQueue.push( { 
        type: 'attribute',
        name: index,
        value: obj.attributes[index]
    });
});
    
moveAlong = function() { // adding products to a shopify cart via ajax api has to be queued
    if (queue.length) {
        var request = queue.shift();                
        
        if (request.type == 'line_item') {
            // need to put data together for jQuery.ajax params POST
            /*
            
            This is an example jQuery.post which works, but I need to use jQuery.ajax I believe for the callbacks and queue. How do I create data with the quantity, id, and properties that will be inserted into the params correctly?
            
            jQuery.post('/cart/add.js', {
              quantity: 4,
              id: 123456789,
              properties: {
                'Line 1': 'Some Value 1',
                'Line 2': 'Some Value 2',
                'Line 3': 'Some Value 3'
              }
            });
            
            */
        } else {
            // need to put data together for jQuery.ajax params POST
        }
        
        var params = {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/cart/add.js',      
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data, textStatus) {moveAlong()},
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {console.log('error occurred.')}
        };
        
        jQuery.ajax(params);
    } else {
        console.log('Finished');
    }  
};
    
moveAlong();
```

```html
Example of json being passed to javascript to parse and queue

<pre>
{
    "line_items":
    [
        {
            "variant_id":"123456789",
            "quantity":4,
            "properties":
            {
                "Line 1":"Some Value 1",
                "Line 2":"Some Value 2",
                "Line 3":"Some Value 3"
            }
        }
    ],
    "products":
    [
        {
            "variant_id":"987654321",
            "quantity":1
        },
        {
            "variant_id":"456987123",
            "quantity":4
        }
    ],
    "attributes":
    [
        {
            "lookup":"lookup value"
        }
    ]
}
</pre>
```

Comment: You know that you can add callbacks to the jQuery.post command, right? `jQuery.post(url, params, function(data) { /* put callback logic here */ });`.

Comment: Update your cart in a separate function using cart.js - the callback to the add.js post wont have all the cart info in it. Instead of your on success you call moveAlong() you can add a cart.js call to that function or make a new one or call cart.js inside of the success portion of your add.js return.